# HttpURLConnection SSL handshake aborted with AWS signed URL redirect

Tags: android, ssl, nginx, amazon-s3, hapi.js

I'm trying to download a file from an Amazon S3 server using Android's HttpURLConnection, but getting an SSLException. Our server is a Node.js server (Hapi) running behind Nginx. The app requests the file from our server, which replies with a 302 redirect to a signed URL of the resource on the S3 server. The code for replying with the redirect is:

```
        var params = {
            Bucket: bucketID, 
            Key: fullPath
        };
        var s3 = new AWS.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });
        s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params, function (err, url)
        {
            if (err || !url)
            {
                return reply(Boom.notFound());
            }

            return reply.redirect(url);

        });
```

Using a browser or curl works fine and correctly redirects to S3 and downloads the file, but on Android using HttpURLConnection (the same problem also happens with HttpClient), I get an SSLException:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x7148d680: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
```

Any idea what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind - it was a mismatch between the TLS versions supported by the app and those supported by the server. The server is set up for TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2, I'm guessing by default HttpURLConnection and HttpClient are set up for TLSv1.0. I'd changed to HttpClient, so adding the following code solved the issue:

```
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.createDefault();
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext,
                                                                          new String[]{"TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"},
                                                                          null,
                                                                          new NoopHostnameVerifier());
        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                .setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore)
                .setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnectionSocketFactory)
                .build();
```